# Scatter Plot of date and numeric value in vba

Tags: vba, excel, plot

To store the dates irrespective of the system format i made it string because the excel will be used by many users on different systems. Below is the code:

```
    Range("Z:Z").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("AC:AC").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("AF:AF").NumberFormat = "@"
    dateArr = Array("4/1/2016", "4/15/2016", "5/1/2016", "5/15/2016", "6/1/2016", "6/15/2016", "7/1/2016", "7/15/2016", "8/1/2016", "8/15/2016", "9/1/2016", "9/15/2016", "10/1/2016", "10/15/2016", "11/1/2016", "11/15/2016", "12/1/2016", "12/15/2016")
    For i = 2 To UBound(dateArr)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 26).Value = Format(dateArr(i - 2), "yyyy/mm/dd")
    Next
```

But i need to plot the scatter plot for it, so i again changed it to the date format as shown below:

```
Columns("Z:Z").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

And when i plotted the scatter plot,its not plotting it properply.

```
  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Plot!$Z$2:$AA$" & date_no_row)
ActiveChart.Axes (xlCategory)
With ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory)
    .MinimumScale = 42401
    .TickLabels.Orientation = 30
    .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    .BaseUnitIsAuto = True
    .MajorUnit = 14
    .MinorUnitIsAuto = True
    .Crosses = xlAutomatic
    .ReversePlotOrder = False
End With
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Plot"
With ActiveChart.Parent
     .Height = 325 ' resize
     .Width = 900  ' resize
     .Top = Range("C3").Top
     .Left = Range("B2").Left
End With
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plot").Chart.HasLegend = False
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plot").Chart
    .HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Dates"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Size = 15
End With

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Plot").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
```

column AA contains numeric values. And the plot i m getting is as shown in the picture below

[image]

And expected plot is

[image]

Comment: "To store the dates irrespective of the system format i made it string": Thats not a good idea. An Excel date will be a number. So it **is** irrespective of the system format already. Only the default date format will be system dependent. But this you can't influence since it is dependent of the  operating system, the Excel is running on, and not of the Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You set column Z to text. After that, you try to set a number format, but the cells are text, so the number format never takes. Try it. Apply the first two code snippets and then manually change the cell format. It will have no effect.

So, start off with the correct format for column Z,

```
Range("Z:Z").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"
```